# Jackson databind security vulnerabilities in ignite version 2.14.0

Tags: ignite

We are using apache ignite v2.14.0 in our project. We regularly check for security vulnerabilities coming from our code base or third-party libraries. We are using aquasec for that purpose. In the security scan for ignite, it has shown 2 high severity vulnerabilities associated with jackson-databind which is heavily used. The version of jackson-databind being used in ignite is 2.12.7.
The CVE numbers for the vulnerabilities are :
CVE-2022-42003
CVE-2022-42004

We need to tell our security team how much impact can these vulnerabilities have on our system and any precautions we can take to avoid these.

The jackson jars are used by internal libraries also, so we can not remove them fully even if we override the jackson version in parent pom and that too can only work for our codebase, ignite will still use 2.12.7.

Answer (score 4):

Jackson Databind has been upgraded to 2.14 in [IGNITE-18108](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-18108)

The fix should be in Apache Ignite 2.15 release, it's better to ask the DEV community for concrete dates, but most likely it will be delivered in Q1 2023.

I suppose you can do one of the following:

- If you are ok with building Ignite from the sources, you might cherry-pick this change and build Ignite from the sources on your own.
- You can check if [GridGain Community Edition](https://www.gridgain.com/) fits your needs. It has a much more frequent release cycle and these CVEs are already fixed in [GG 8.8.23](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/release-notes/8.8.23/release-notes_8.8.23#enterprise-edition-changes)
- Wait for Ignite 2.15.